# What is the difference between listeners and adapters?

Tags: java, swing, awt, adapter, listeners

I'm trying to differentiate between listeners and adapters.

Are they pretty much the same but in listeners you have to implement all the methods in the interface, but with adapters you have an option to only implement the methods you need so the code is cleaners and easier to read?

I also got told that adapters enable instantiation with only one implementation and you can't instantiate listeners, I don't fully understand this.

Can someone please explain which one is better to use and things you can do with one but you can't with the other?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) is `interface` which force you to `override` all of the methods, while [WindowAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) is implementation of `WindowListener` and you only need to `override` the method(s) that you interest to deal with.

`WindowListener` is interface which mean you cant instantiation the `WindowListener`, while `WindowAdapter` is concrete class that you can use `new` operator to instantiation.

When you use `WindowAdapter`, the code is more clean where your class only override the method(s) that you want.
For example:

### WindowListener

```
public class CloseListener implements WindowListener {
    // im not interest  on this event, but still need to override it
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {

    }
    // im not interest  on this event, but still need to override it    
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);

    }
    // im not interest  on this event, but still need to override it    
    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {

    }
    // im not interest  on this event, but still need to override it
    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {

    }

}
```

### WindowAdapter

While using adapter the code is cleaner:

```
// at JFrame class
addWindowListener(new CloseListener());

// reusable Close Listener
public class CloseListener extends WindowAdapter {
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Or

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
         System.exit(0);
     }
});
```

So I would recommend to use `WindowAdapter`, but not **must follow**. However, two of the API about the same just that `WindowAdapter` exists as convenience for creating listener objects.

EDIT:

Since `WindowListener` is `interface`, you can implement it at your JFrame subclass.

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements WindowListener {
    // this is ok
}
public class MainWindow extends JFrame, WindowAdapter {
    // this is not allow
}
```

But you cant do it with `WindowAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind also letting me know what it means by 'adapters enable instantiation with only one implementation and you can't instantiate listeners'

Comment: the listener interface is usually just that - an interface - so you cant create a new listener, you need to create a new instance of some class implementing this interface.
adapters, on the other hand, may be instantiated directly (if they're not abstract) - but they usually do nothing by default so there's no real use-case for creating them

Comment: Thanks a very good answer. I still don't get why you would want to instantiate a adapter class. Examples of when this would be done will be useful. :)

Comment: It could make sense if you are reusing the adapter/listener to register to multiple objects. So you could for instance have a `KeyAdapter` that just refreshes something. And you want that behaviour on several JTextFields or so... Then you can create an instance and `addKeyListener(...)` that instance to all of them instead of creating multiple anonymous versions. Although I am also not exactly sure what Pau Kiat Wee meant with his statement...

Answer (score 8):

You can do everything with either, but if you start with the interface, your code is going to have a LOT of boilerplate. I'm sure you noticed that when you tried it out. That statement about instantiation etc. is a quite convoluted way of saying it and there's a lot of confusion of terms. You can write

```
c.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
  @Override public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) { }
  @Override public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) { System.exit(0); }
  @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) { }
  @Override public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) { }
  @Override public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) { }
  @Override public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) { }
  @Override public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) { }
});
```

or you can write

```
c.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  @Override public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) { System.exit(0); }
});
```

In neither case are you **instantiating** either `WindowListener` or `WindowAdapter`—you are creating anonymous classes that implement `WindowListener`/extend `WindowAdapter`. But when you implement the interface directly, you are forced to implement all methods, wheras when you extend the adapter class, you can only override what you need. That class already has exactly these empty implementations that you had to write in the `Listener` case.

Comment: I think your second code sample means to create an instance of `WindowAdapter` and not `WindowListener`

Comment: This is the only answer that cleared my understanding of the difference! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are several Adapter classes such as the MouseAdapter, KeyAdapter, WindowAdapter that one can extend thus avoiding writing the methods that you don't actuality need.

The thing with interfaces is that you have to write out all the methods you do not need. The Adapter class can further be Sub Classed as a way to override the method required.

http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week7/19.html

Answer (score 0):

Listeners are used when you plan to utilize most of the interface methods. When you need to use only a few of the methods an adapter would be better b/c you would not have to override the remainder of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is another aspect which is not addressed in other answers: API evolution. Providing adapter classes (a.k.a empty or default implementations of interfaces) makes introducing new methods in interfaces less painful. If an API provides only interfaces then clients are forced to implement them and if a new method is added to the interfaces then all implementing classes will break. However, if default implementations are provided then clients have the chance to extend those instead which, apart from being convenient, helps them upgrading to newer API version. With [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) of Java 8 default/empty implementation have become less important but they might be handy in older versions.