# Problems calling a class with static main

Tags: java, image, background, overriding, mainclass

I was wondering how this would interfere with the main class when called, I have found no suitable way to make a main class and call it in a final.

```
 import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.imageio.*;
  import javax.swing.*;


 class Converter extends JFrame  implements 
 KeyListener, ItemListener, MouseListener {


//insert body here//    


@Override
        public void paintComponents (Graphics g)  {g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 20, 500,210, this);
        super.paintComponents (g);
        Color transparent = new Color (0, true);
        background.setBackground(transparent);
        repaint ();
        background.setVisible(true);
        pack();
        setContentPane(background);
        background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add (background);
        }    
            }











  class ShowconverterFrame  {
     public static void main (String args []) {
        new Converter ();
        }
}
```

Hi I am trying to figure out why this wont work... any help is appreciated! It returns with "no main class found" and that it cannot be declared as static. I just added this piece to the body and all of the sudden the whole things stops working. I have been trying to implement a JPanel in which I have an JLabel that is an image.

Comment: Because I didn't receive the paycheck from you to go over your code.

Comment: is there any way I could make it easier for you?

Comment: Yeah start-over and build one functionality at a time. This looks like a very bad copy paste job. And next time you ask a question here, be more specific about what you've tried and what the error is. Also post small bits of executable code.

Comment: Is this better to process, and by one functionality at a time do you mean building each button as a separate class then calling the class in the main?

Comment: count your curly brackets for starters. And remove those ..... (periods)

Comment: Note that `paintComponents` should be `paintComponent`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first of all: there's more to your Converter class, right **(Later edit: when I wrote this I was referring to the initial, longer code you had posted)**? You have implemented all the methods in those 3 interfaces? In case you don't need them all, I suggest you take a look at Adapters. Here's a topic in which the differences between Listeners and Adapters are discussed:
[What is the difference between listeners and adapters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470104/what-is-the-difference-between-listeners-and-adapters). It feels rather bad practice to implement so many interfaces with so many methods to override if you don't need all of them.

Now, if your Converter class is fully functional, a functional entry-point class should look like this:

```
public class ShowconverterFrame  {
     public static void main (String [] args) {
        new Converter().setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

Put this code in a different .java file in the same package(named ShowconverterFrame.java) and run it. Also, if you're not using an IDE, Netbeans is easy to use for beginners, it would help you a lot. :)

Aaand... the serial version id has the following purpose: [What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it) . As you can see, it has nothing to do with the answer to your question, but it's good to know.

Comment: Yes, there is more to my converter class, I had buttons and panels attached to it. I have adapters on them, but I took down the full program as i am new to this and people were asking for a simpler piece to work with. My main method cannot be declared static. As a result my  main will not be found and the program will exit. I am not using an IDE. I am downloading Netbeans right now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: should I show the full thing, would that help?